# PHP password hashing and match-up problems

Tags: php

Basically what would I need to add to this code in the `login.php` to match the hash created in the `register.php`:

**login.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['email'];
        $store_password = $_POST['pword'];
        check($username, $store_password);
    }
    function check($username, $pword){
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Registrar');
        $check = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='$username'";
        $check_q = mysqli_query($conn, $check) or die("<div class='loginmsg'>Error on checking Username<div>");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($check_q) == 1) {
            login($username, $pword);
        }
        else{
            echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Wrong Email or Password</div>";
        }
    }


function login($username, $pword){
  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Registrar');
      $login = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='$username'  and pword='$pword'";
      $login_q = mysqli_query($conn, $login) or die('Error on checking Username and Password');
      if (mysqli_num_rows($login_q) == 1){
    header('Location: account.php');
    echo"<div id='loginmsg'> Logged in as $username </div>";
          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      }
      else {
          echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Wrong Password </div>";
      }
  }
```

to match the password hash in the `register.php`

**register.php:**

```
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pword = $_POST['pword'];
$store_password = password_hash('pword', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And you need to show how you're storing the password (I hope you mean 'hash', you **NEVER** store the raw cleartext password), and how you do the cryping/hashing/comparing.

Comment: pull the hash from the database `SELECT pword FROM users WHERE email=?` then compare with `password_verify($userSubmittedPassword, $hashFromDatabase)` And as @MarcB eludes to, use prepared statements to query, not string interpolation

Comment: The hash is stored in the database, not the plain text password, correct?

Comment: You are vulnerable? possible, but maybe the `login()` function gets cleaned/escaped data at this point ;)

Comment: @pmahomme yes the hash is stored.

Comment: @AJRIley ok, have a look at what Steve said above.

Comment: @Marc B of course the hash is being stored correctly. its just not matching up the passwords.

Comment: Who gives the hint that the stuff after `header('Location: account.php');` will not be printed on page, because of the redirect! Oh, it was me.

Comment: @AJRIley: then you need to show you retrieve/compare hashes. The above code is essentially USELESS for debugging, since it's NOT the code causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use function password_verify like this

```
if (password_verify($given_password, $stored_password)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

So you have to retrieve the results from db for the given username and compare the password.

In fact

```
    function login($username, $pword){
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Registrar');
        $login = "SELECT email, pword FROM Users WHERE email='$username'";
        $login_q = mysqli_query($conn, $login) or die('Error on checking Username and Password');
        if (mysqli_num_rows($login_q) == 1){
  if(password_verify($pword, mysqli_fetch_field($login_q,1))){
      header('Location: account.php');
      echo"<div id='loginmsg'> Logged in as $username </div>";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        }
  else {
    echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Wrong Password </div>";
        }
  }
  else {
    echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Unknown Username </div>";
}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, only problem is where exactly would this go for it to work? in context to my login function?

Comment: thank you again, mysqli_fetch_field() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given..seems to be the only issue now

Comment: Sorry maybe my answer is incomplete, I do not have my notes now, but the meaning is this.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate tasks, you will want to have maybe 2-4 or so functions (or methods via a class). Here is a really simple example of the workflow. I am going to use PDO because I know it better:

```
// This is just simple but you can make this as elaborate as you want, but
// if you always use the same function to connect, you will will find troubleshooting
// that much easier.
function connection()
    {
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Registrar','root','root');
    }
// You want to make a simple validation function where that's all it does,
// you don't want to put a bunch of html in here because you can reuse this function
// elsewhere in other scripts if need be.
function validate($email,$password,$con)
    {
        // Just look up by email only
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `email`= ?";
        $query = $con->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($email));
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // If you don't get a row, just return false (didn't validate)
        if(empty($result['email']))
            return false;
        // $result['password'] should have been stored as a hash using password_hash()
        return password_verify($password,$result['password']);
    }
// Do a quick updater to make it easier on yourself.
// You don't use this in this script but it gives you an idea about what to
// do when you are saving passwords via password_hash()
function updatePassword($email,$password,$con)
    {
        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $sql = 'UPDATE `Users` set `password` = ? where `email` = ?';
        $query = $con->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($hash,$email));
    }

session_start();
$con = connection();
// Check there is a post and that post is valid email address
// At this point you can add more messaging for errors...
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Run our validation function
    $valid = validate($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$con);
    if($valid) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['email'];
        header('Location: account.php');
        exit;
    }
    else {
        die("<div id='loginmsg'>Wrong Password</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this kind of confuses me :P

Comment: Well (in my opinion) the more human-readable you can make your code the better. Functions allow you to do that. They also allow consistency because you can reuse the functions. A login function should be the business part, the part that checks the username and password and reports to the view what to show the user. You should break your code down to smaller, more human-readable parts